# External HD changed partition map

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition, guid

Apparently my external HD went crazy (I've been using it without problem for a long time) and decided to change partition scheme from GUID to FDisk (look at disk1) but my data remains as HFS+ (disk1s2)...

[image]

[image]

I have important data in that HD, so my question is

> Is there a way to repair this change in partition scheme without losing my data??
>
> Which blocks do I need to delete to create the new GPT scheme?

I have found a program called **textdisk** that seems to be able to do it but I am afraid of erasing the data by accident.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** Tried Klanomath suggestion in: [Need help deciphering TestDisk results to fix HDD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250297/need-help-deciphering-testdisk-results-to-fix-hdd) and changed to GPT scheme but got error during verification.

[image]

Comment: It's possible to repair the disk without *textdisk* (TestDisk?). There are already some questions & answers here. I'll try to find the proper one and add a link here.

Comment: Here is the proper answer: [Accidently deleted some small sized partitions when installing Windows. OSX Partition wont boot](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/251868/93229). You have to replace disk0 by disk1 in David's answer: `...unmountdisk  /dev/disk1
fdisk  -e  /dev/disk1  <<<...`

Comment: @klanomath Thanks! Edited question, but gonna take a look at that. Already changed to GPT scheme but still won't mount.

Comment: Which answer of mine ("Klanomath's suggestion") are you referring to in your question?

Comment: @klanomath  sorry, didn't include link but was this one: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250297/need-help-deciphering-testdisk-results-to-fix-hdd

Comment: Hmm, what happened with the external disk? Did you attach it to a PC?

Comment: @klanomath nope, only thing I did was update OS X to "El Capitan"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46141/discussion-between-klanomath-and-luis-vera).