# My question is about recreating Corestorage partitions - formatted Fusion drive

Tags: partition, core-storage

I have an iMac 27" with a Fusion Disk (SSD 121 GB, HDD 1 TB) and Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) installed.

The HDD failed and the Fusion Drive is lost (Lions recovery diskutil: disk missing - fix/ignore)

After the incident both disks were cloned to external 1TB HDD each. The failed HDD was replaced by a new 2 TB disk. I cloned both disks back to internal.

For more than one month I am playing with creating new GPT structure on SSD/HDD.
Now I would like to revive SSD with correct partitions.

I went through lot of klanomoath posts, how to find corestage partition with disk editor, [how to find and calculate start and size](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202018/how-to-fix-guid-hard-drive-corrupted-to-mbr) of P1 and P2, etc. Also used the excel tool for calculating right numbers. Not lucky at all. I don't know, what should I see, if the SSD partitions are correctly set.
Thank you for any help.

Details of my SSD and steps done are:

SSD (disk1)
looking for Corestage partition#2 -i 2 (part of lost fusion drive):

```
Total blocks: 236978176 
BlockOffset2 = 236715990 (second HFSJ)   
StartBlockOfVolume2 = 236715988 (BlockOffset2-2)
Rule 6. empty space 262144 blocks (should be the size of part#3)
EndBlockOfVolume1 = 236715988-262144-1 = 236453843 
SizeOfVolume1 =    236453843-409640+1=236044204 
LastBlockOfVolume2 =    236978176-1-32-7-262144-1 = 236715991 
SizeOfVolume2 =    236715991-236715988+1=4 (this is something pointing at JHFS+ and not corestage)

diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk1
sudo gpt destroy /dev/disk1
diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk1
sudo gpt create -f /dev/disk1
sudo gpt add -b 40 -i 1 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B disk1
sudo gpt add -b 236715988 -i 3 -s  262144 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk1
sudo gpt add -b 409640 -i 2 -s  236044204 -t 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk1
```

Comment: 1. How did you clone the SSD to the 1st 1TB drive? 2. How have you been able to clone a **broken** HDD? 3. How did you clone the HDD to the 2nd 1TB drive? (i.e. did you clone the (broken) drives to files or to partitions/drives)

Comment: I cloned SSD with the same mac, OS X from external disk. with disk cloning utility (DATA RESCUE 4). I cloned the hdd  with clonezilla, But I am not sure, if it went all right. Now I can see with fsck_cs disk1s2 (on SSD) something like this: MacBook-Air-uzivatela-Mano:~ mano$ sudo fsck_cs disk1s2
    Load and verify Segment Cleaning
** The volume 2E7B6CDB-99DD-4F57-ACE4-E9B25E66D66C appears to be OK <br/> How can I post what fsck_cs is responding? Too long output...

Comment: SSD is cloned drive to drive without errors. Restored back to sad with iBored (hex disk editor) block copy from external disk (the cloned one). I can see CS partition on 409640, the fsck_cs on disk1s2 tells it is a corestage and that is OK. I am not sure with P3, if the size should be 262144 or 1269536 (this has no place on disk) You can connect with Teamviever if you want.

Comment: SSD is also a problem, because by mistake I made with diskutil cs (I cannot remember what) on the SSD clone after I let the OS X Lion to "repair" the fusion drive by "fix", so I lost the original ssd :-( and have only the "spoiled" copy of sad. But I am sure, there are the data, because I can recover with Easeus data recovery all files with names, but the data are on the HDD, so I cannot recover files.

Comment: Without direct access it's almost impossible (based on the details given) to determine whether it's possible to recover/restore the Fusion drive. The excel sheet was made for a different purpose (deleted GUID partition table) and doesn't really help much here.

Comment: why not try Teamviewer? Mac is running OS X Sierra from external drive, you can have access to SSD and HDD. Disk1 and Disk0. There is the copy of failed HDD as Disk4. You could see also the file structure recovered from SSD (filenames with dates and correct sizes). I can also see with another tool that disk0 (HDD) is corestage. It is very promising, but I am not able to go forward. If there would be somebody willing to help, I would also go for a professional service. You are the only guy who know the details, please help me, there are very important files on the disk. Can we chat privately?

Comment: Hello klanomath, please respond if you can. I need to  dd the disk4s2 to disk1s2, but Mac restarts after this command immediately. disk1s2 is part of the Fusion Drive and I do not know how to unmount the corestorage Drive.

Comment: klanomath pls. are you online? I cannot catch you on gmail, i would like to ask you to look at my problem through Teamviewer. I brought the hdd from recovery company and dd it to disk1. Please respond. Thx.