# Recover data from external hard drive partition Mac OS X

Tags: mac, external-disk, data-recovery, hfs+, guid

A couple of weeks ago, I dropped my external drive while a program was writing data to it. The drive seems to spin up fine, without beeps/scratches. The drive also has EFI and Recovery partitions. One of the two data partitions also mounts. I need to recover data from the other partition; any help will be appreciated.

I'm not sure if my issue is related to [this question and its solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202018/how-to-fix-guid-hard-drive-corrupted-to-mbr), but I used wxHexEditor to go to the offset for the partition in question, and did not see the HFSJ string in the third block. Every time I try searching for all possible instances for HFSJ, it takes too long and eventually the program becomes unresponsive.

I'm attaching the results of various tests on the drive. The partition I want to recover from is "HDD WD...", I don't care about the rest.

diskutil list /dev/disk2

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
#: TYPE                  NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0: GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
1: EFI                   EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
2: Apple_HFS             BackupPT                1000.0 GB  disk2s2
3: Apple_HFS             HDD WD                  999.2 GB   disk2s3
4: Apple_Boot            Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk2s4
```

diskutil info /dev/disk2

```
Device Identifier:        disk2
Device Node:              /dev/disk2
Whole:                    Yes
Part of Whole:            disk2
Device / Media Name:      Mobile

Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)
Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)
File System:              None

Content (IOContent):      GUID_partition_scheme
OS Can Be Installed:      No
Media Type:               Generic
Protocol:                 USB
SMART Status:             Not Supported

Disk Size:                2.0 TB (2000365289472 Bytes) (exactly 3906963456 512-Byte-Units)
Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

Read-Only Media:          No
Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)

Device Location:          External
Removable Media:          Fixed

Virtual:                  No
```

fdisk /dev/disk2

```
Disk: /dev/disk2    geometry: 243197/255/63 [3906963456 sectors]
Signature: 0x0
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

gpt recover /dev/disk2

```
gpt recover: unable to open device '/dev/disk2': Resource busy
```

gpt -r -vv show /dev/disk2

```
gpt show: /dev/disk2: mediasize=2000365289472; sectorsize=512; blocks=3906963456
gpt show: /dev/disk2: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk2: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk2: Sec GPT at sector 3906963455
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  1953125000      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1953534640      262144         
  1953796784  1951634952      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  3905431736      262144         
  3905693880     1269536      4  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  3906963416           7         
  3906963423          32         Sec GPT table
  3906963455           1         Sec GPT header
```