# Rebuild partition table on external HDD - not writable

Tags: partition, data-recovery, hfs+, guid

I have an external hard drive formatted with 3 HFS+ partitions. To cut a long story short I had it connected to a Windows PC and accidentally started formatting the drive to NTFS. As soon as I realised what was happening I disconnected the drive, but the partition table is corrupted. I used TestDisk to gather info about the partitions, and tried to use pDisk to rebuild the partition table, but when I try to do that, I get the message that the partition table is not writable, the device is busy. Anyone know how I can rewrite the partition table?

Update:

The TestDisk results are like this (for settings on Apple Partition Map - I don't know if this is the correct settings, but it's the only one which gives 3 distinct partitions):

```
Start:     262208 End:  419692607 Size: 419430400
Start:  419954752 End: 1258815551 Size: 838860800
Start: 1259077696 End: 1953525151 Size: 694447456
```

Does that look OK?

Comment: Hmmm... What are  the units? Blocks? I don't have a TestDisk at hand right now... And what's the total size of your disk in Bytes (not GB!)/blocks?

Comment: The units are sectors, and TestDisk says it is 931GiB, with a total of 1953525168 sectors.

Comment: Do you remember how you formatted the disk? GUID or Apple Partition Map? And do you remember the approximate sizes of your volumes?

Comment: I think it was os x journaled (in Disk Utility) but it was long time ago so not sure, sizes - I can't remember, I'd guess at around 300GB each.

Comment: I have to test this in a VM: First I create a disk with GUID partition table and then with an Apple Partition Table. WIll take some time...

Comment: What would happen if I rebuilt the partition table with the wrong values? Lost data?

Comment: @IanDoble Rebuilding/writing a partition table just writes to the first few blocks of a disk. If the values are wrong the partition(s) will fail to mount because a proper file system is missing/can't be detected. Often you will be asked to initialize it. DON'T INITIALIZE it. Just remove the partition table or enter other values.

Comment: Hmmm. I initialized it in Windows before I started to format it, before I unplugged it when I realised I was doing it to the wrong disk.

Comment: @IanDoble The TestDisk results indicate that the formatting with Windows wasn't (very) successful. I've created a virtual disk with the same size as yours and partitioned it like you did. All the sizes or delta-sizes are typical for an Apple Partition map. So use the 2nd part of my answer. Just try it. Simply creating a partition map doesn't harm the data on your disk. If you create a false partition map it's like creating a wrong index for a book: the content of the book won't be touched but you can't find the proper paragraphs.

Comment: That seemed to work perfectly for the first two partitions, but for the last one it said "error: no space available on device". The only thing I didn't do from your instructions was rebuild the EFI entry, as I thought it wasn't a GUID disk.

Comment: @IanDoble You are right: Apple Partition Table doesn't contain an entry for EFI. EFI is GPT only. I will recheck the proper command for the last partition.

Comment: @IanDoble The command for the last partition below seems to be correct: `First block: 1259077696 Length in blocks: 694447456`. Did you enter the values manually or by copy/paste?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29688/discussion-between-ian-dobie-and-klanomath).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Klanomath for the invaluable help - the above solution worked for two of the partitions using the values generated by TestDisk, but it wouldn't let me do the third, saying there was not enough space. In the end, this solution did work for me and the disk works as it used to:
http://perrohunter.com/repair-a-mac-os-x-hfs-partition-table/

Answer (score 4):

OS X uses three different types of valid partition tables. Only one of those is written to a particular disk:

- [GUID partition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)
- [Apple Partition Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Partition_Map)
- MBR

The default partition table on OS X is the GUID partition table.

Depending on the previously used partition table on your disk you have to use different tools to create/change/write it:

- gpt for GUID partition table
- pdisk for Apple Partition Table
- fdisk for MBR

After additional informations given by the OP (testdisk results) and checking it in a virtual machine it's highly probable that the disk was formatted with an Apple Partition Map. Consequently use pdisk to rebuild the partition map.

**pdisk:**

A typical disk formatted with an Apple Partition Table looks like this:

```
Driver Descriptor Map: Block 0              Size:      1 Block
Apple Partition Table: Block 1 - 63         Size:     63 Blocks
Apple_Free:            Block 64 - 262207    Size: 262144 Blocks
1st partition:         Block 262208 - 
Apple_Free:                                 Size: 262144 Blocks
...
Apple_Free:                                 Size: 262144 Blocks
last partition
Apple_Free:                                 Size:     16 Blocks
```

To recreate the partition map do the following:

- attach the external drive
- detach any other external drive
- open Terminal and enter `diskutil list` to get the DiskIdentifier (in the step below I assume your DiskIdentifier is disk1
- enter `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk1`
- enter `sudo pdisk /dev/rdisk1`  You will get the following output:

  > Edit /dev/rdisk1 -
  >   Command (? for help):
- Now enter `c` then enter the start block, the size of the first partition and the name. You have to hit the enter key after every input. Repeat this for the next two partitions. At the end it should look like this:

  > Command (? for help): c
  >   First block: 262208
  >   Length in blocks: 419430400
  >   Name of partition: part1
  >   Command (? for help): c
  >   First block: 419954752
  >   Length in blocks: 838860800
  >   Name of partition: part2
  >   Command (? for help): c
  >   First block: 1259077696
  >   Length in blocks: 694447456
  >   Name of partition: part3
  >   Command (? for help):
- At the last prompt enter `w` then `y` to write the changes to disk and finally `q`to quit pdisk:

  > Command (? for help): w
  >   Writing the map destroys what was there before. Is that okay? [n/y]: y
  >   The partition table has been altered!
  >
  > Command (? for help):
- The missing volumes should mount automatically. Otherwise enter `diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk1`. Enter `q` at the last prompt to quit pdisk, then quit Terminal, open Disk Utility and check the recovered volumes for errors.

---

**gpt:**

In the example below I assume the DiskIdentifier of your external disk is disk1 (check this with `diskutil list`)

First you have to unmount the external disk:

```
diskutil umountDisk disk1
```

Remove the current MBR and create a GPT with gpt:

```
sudo gpt create -f /dev/disk1
```

First rebuild the EFI entry with:

```
sudo gpt add -b 40 -i 1 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B disk1
```

The EFI partition is a fixed sized partition near the beginning of every GUID partitioned disk (using OS X partitioning tools)

Then add the JHFS+ partition entries with the TestDisk findings:

```
sudo gpt add -b StartBlock -i IndexNumber -s SizeOfVolume -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk1
```

Example for the first OS X partition:

```
sudo gpt add -b 409640 -i 2 -s SizeOfHFSVolume1 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk1
```

After adding a partition with gpt you may have to unmount disk1 with `diskutil umountDisk disk1` again if your get a "resource is busy" error adding additional partitions.

Increase the index number by 1 for every new partition.

Listed below are answers to similar questions (partly covering other file systems like ExFAT)

- [How to fix GUID hard drive corrupted to MBR?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202018/how-to-fix-guid-hard-drive-corrupted-to-mbr)
- [HFS+ invalid number of allocation blocks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176777/hfs-invalid-number-of-allocation-blocks)
- [Hard drive no longer accessible](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177553/hard-drive-no-longer-accessible)

If you run into problems, leave a comment to the answer with @klanomath.

Comment: This question needs your attention @klanomath
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360151/accidentally-overwrote-encrypted-external-drive-mac-os

Comment: @klanomath If you could have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361179/external-hdd-with-encrypted-mac-partitions-is-no-longer-recognized that'd be appreciated.