# HELP ME PLEASE - Partition of External Disk APFS is broken

Tags: mac, hard-drive, partition, apfs

In advance sorry for my very rusty English... I have an external disk where a partition is broken. I bought another identical external disk to try to substitute the partition with `sudo gpt add` and `sudo dd` like someone wrote here [please see the short example](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219902/partition-map-rebuild)

If I write `sudo gpt -r show disk2` for my broken disk I obtain this:

```
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34        2014         
        2048  3906961368      1  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  3906963416           7         
  3906963423          32         Sec GPT table
  3906963455           1         Sec GPT header
```

If I write `sudo gpt -r show disk2` for my new empty disk I obtain this:

```
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  3906553776      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  3906963416           7         
  3906963423          32         Sec GPT table
  3906963455           1         Sec GPT header
```

Please please someone very good people can help me to fix my broken disk to recover all photos of my life. I am in a panic!!!!

Comment: Oh no! Main thing is to not panic - you will have many chances to image the data, seek data recovery. You only get one shot to issue a command that might destroy more data or a copy of the filesystem or disk descriptors. Take two or three days to plan your next move / fix is my advice.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a second disk, one option is to let software designed to restore files take a read only pass and tell you what they found.

- https://www.prosofteng.com/mac-data-recovery

Once you know your photos are safe, the stakes to fix the partition table are lower. I’ll leave discussion on the steps to rebuild your disk to the experts, but wanted to remind everyone to get a backup or image (disk utility could perform a block for block copy of the old drive to the new one) is a good option.

Taking a week or at least three days to plan your next move is the safe plan.