# My whole startup disk has gone blank

Tags: macbook-pro, error, recovery, disk-format, internet-recovery

After a botched arch Linux install, my whole ssd got wiped. I used a bootable USB drive for Ubuntu to see what happened and saw that all my partitions from the SSD had vanished and the drive was showing up as free space. I am loading up internet recovery but I am not sure what I'll do there.

Everything went to hell after I typed 
`parted mklabel gpt /dev/disk2` or something similar along these lines.

I don't care about recovering my data but all I want is my MacBook to boot up again

System: MacBook Pro Retina Display late 2011

Comment: Depends on what the installer tried to do. I've seen nix installers completely wipe & repartition the drive for their own use. What you do next depends on how recent your backup is.

Comment: @Tetsujin what if I don't have another backup.

Comment: @klanomath All my data HAS been erased and I don't care at this point, just want my MacBook to boot up again

Comment: @klanomath how would one do that? You have given me hope :)

Comment: @klanomath Yes it did. The installed OSX was el Capitan 11.2 I think. I am not sure about the version number but surely was el Capitan

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/206593/100047 I found your answer in another thread, is this what I have to do?

Comment: @user2758186 It's similar yes. But I'm already writing an answer - which will take some time

Comment: I ran into something similar the other day.  What I did was boot a Live USB version of Linux (Ubuntu) and format the disk ExtFAT with an MBR partition.  Once I did that, the OS X installer was able to find and partition the disk normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Granted that gparted didn't erase/secure erase data (overwriting important parts of your disk with zeros or arbitrary data) you probably can recreate the old standard GUID partition table which follows a fixed Apple scheme. gparted or similar gpt partitioning executables usually only modify the first and last 34 blocks (512 B) or 6 blocks (4096 B) of a disk.

The **fast** approach below won't work, if you've modified the disk previously (e.g installed Windows, resized the main volume **and** added a second partition). It only works with the "vanilla" OS X install partition scheme.

Recreating the old GUID partition table should restore the previous volume(s). Here is a related answer: [HFS+ invalid number of allocation blocks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176777/hfs-invalid-number-of-allocation-blocks).

The standard Apple GUID partition scheme looks like that:

```
                0           1         PMBR
                1           1         Pri GPT header
                2          32         Pri GPT table
               34           6         
               40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
           409640  part2-size      2  GPT part - partition type
part2-size+409640     1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
    total_size-40           7         
    total_size-33          32         Sec GPT table
     total_size-1           1         Sec GPT header
```

Here *total-size* is the total size of the disk in 512 B-blocks. *part2-size* usually is *total-size - 1679216* in 512 B-blocks.

The partition type of the second partition is either 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC (CoreStorage) or 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC (HFS+).

Newer systems on SSDs preferably have a CoreStorage- and older systems on HDDs an HFS+-type main partition.

**Preparation:**

- Detach any external drive
- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.

  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot into a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an Apple/Akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.

  Alternatively you may start from a bootable installer thumb drive (preferably Yosemite or El Capitan) or a thumb drive containing a full system (preferably Yosemite or El Capitan). If you boot to a full system and login as admin you have to prepend `sudo` to execute some commands like `gpt ...` or `newfs_hfs ...`!

**Remove the an old/wrong MBR/GUID partition table**

- Enter `diskutil list` and `gpt -r show /dev/diskX` (with x=0,1,2,3 etc) to get an overview. Usually the internal disk has the disk identifier disk0. Below I assume your internal disk is disk0.
- Enter `gpt destroy /dev/disk0` to remove any current GUID pt.
- Enter `gpt create -f /dev/disk0` to create a new empty GPT partition table and replace any MBR by an PMBR.

**Restore previous partitions**

- EFI:

  ```
  gpt add -b 40 -i 1 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B /dev/disk0
  ```
- Recovery partition:

  Now do the math: the start block *$sbrecovery* of the Recovery HD is *total-size - 1269576*. *$sbrecovery* has to be dividable by 8!

  ```
  gpt add -b $sbrecovery -i 3 -s 1269536 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B /dev/disk0
  ```
- Main volume

  Do the math again: the size of the volume *$mainvolumesize* is *total-size - 1679216*. *$mainvolumesize* has to be divisible by 8! Your main volume may either be a CoreStorage or a HFS+-type partition. Here I assume it's the first one:

  ```
  gpt add -b 409640 -i 2 -s $mainvolumesize -t 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  ```
- Now check if diskutil list finds a CoreStorage volume:

  ```
  diskutil cs list
  ```

  If the GUUID partition table is properly restored and your main partition was a CoreStorage volume you should get an output similar to this one:

  ```
    CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
  |
  +-- Logical Volume Group A629E051-D7B0-4B8C-A803-074F62704636
      =========================================================
      Name:         System
      Status:       Online
      Size:         53946696192 B (53.9 GB)
      Free Space:   16777216 B (16.8 MB)
      |
      +-< Physical Volume 90C09FC0-4215-4871-901B-70E2C9C7D464
      |   ----------------------------------------------------
      |   Index:    0
      |   Disk:     disk0s2
      |   Status:   Online
      |   Size:     53946696192 B (53.9 GB)
      |
      +-> Logical Volume Family F6962E38-50E4-4458-BFE6-CF2E179352F5
          ----------------------------------------------------------
          Encryption Status:       Unlocked
          Encryption Type:         None
          Conversion Status:       NoConversion
          Conversion Direction:    -none-
          Has Encrypted Extents:   No
          Fully Secure:            No
          Passphrase Required:     No
          |
          +-> Logical Volume BD36C73D-860D-4DC6-B125-AD624F448B88
              ---------------------------------------------------
              Disk:                  disk2
              Status:                Online
              Size (Total):          53496696192 B (53.5 GB)
              Conversion Progress:   -none-
              Revertible:            Yes (no decryption required)
              LV Name:               System
              Volume Name:           System
              Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
  ```
- verify the CoreStorage volume with

  ```
  diskutil verifyVolume diskX
  ```

  (in the above CoreStorage example diskX is disk2 - check **(Disk of Logical Volume)**, your diskX probably is disk14 or disk15)

If you get an error or no output your main volume either is a HFS+-type partition or the boundaries of the partition are wrong.

- Then try the following and remove the CoreStorage-type partition and create an HFS+-type partition instead:

  ```
  gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0
  gpt add -b 409640 -i 2 -s $mainvolumesize -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  ```
- Verify the volume:

  ```
  diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk0s2
  ```

---

If you run into problems or get strange errors please post a comment to the answer!

Comment: +1 as always. You're good at this stuff :) I do hope if ever I have an unbacked drive fall over at any point in future you're still here to help out.

Comment: @Tetsujin My current average live expectancy according to [Statistisches Bundesamt](https://www.destatis.de/EN/Homepage.html) is 14.4 years. On the one hand I'm smoking - so it might be less - on the other hand I had a dream that I will die as a 93 year-old... ;-)

Comment: Dammit... I *might* just outlive you.... well, maybe if I give up smoking. I'm hoping for the 'out of bell-curve' too, I'm thinking 117 might be a decent age to finally retire :)

Comment: wow thanks for the help! I have an exam tomorrow so I have to study for it. I will definitely try this out tomorrow though.

Comment: who cares about the exam. I did what you said and my MacBook works! I think I formatted my drive a while back because the data isn't there but all is fine.

Comment: @user2758186 Did you get a `diskutil cs list` output?