# Fix external disk unplugged

Tags: terminal, mac, external-disk, mount

i can´t fix this external disk

```
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk3
   1:                       0xA2                         1.0 TB     disk3s1
   2:                       0xA2                         49.4 MB    disk3s2


gpt show: /dev/disk3: mediasize=1000170586112; sectorsize=512; blocks=1953458176
gpt show: /dev/disk3: MBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk3: MBR part: type=162, start=63, size=1953343287
gpt show: /dev/disk3: MBR part: type=162, start=1953343350, size=96390
gpt show: /dev/disk3: Bad CRC in GPT table at sector 2
gpt show: /dev/disk3: Sec GPT at sector 1953458175
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         MBR
           1          62         
          63  1953343287      1  MBR part 162
  1953343350       96390      2  MBR part 162
  1953439740       18403         
  1953458143          32         Sec GPT table
  1953458175           1         Sec GPT header



sh-3.2# sudo fsck_hfs -q /dev/disk3
** /dev/rdisk3 (NO WRITE)
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-366.30.3).
volumeType is 0
0000:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
01b0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 1a93 bde5 0000 0001       |................|
01c0:  0100 a2fe bff5 3f00 0000 37a7 6d74 0000       |..........7.mt..|
01d0:  81f6 a2fe bffb 76a7 6d74 8678 0100 0000       |......v.mt.x....|
01e0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
01f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 55aa       |..............U.|
QUICKCHECK ONLY; NO HFS SIGNATURE FOUND

sh-3.2# sudo fdisk -r /dev/rdisk3
fdisk: could not open MBR file /usr/standalone/i386/boot0: No such file or directory
```

any solution???

this?

```
sh-3.2# sudo fdisk -u /dev/rdisk3
fdisk: could not open MBR file /usr/standalone/i386/boot0: No such file or directory

    -----------------------------------------------------
    ------ ATTENTION - UPDATING MASTER BOOT RECORD ------
    -----------------------------------------------------

Do you wish to write new MBR? [n] n
```

Comment: Which format should the partition actually have?

Comment: Bad cyclical redundancy check in the GUID partition table makes it sound like an erase and reformat might prove helpful. "GUID Partition Table (GPT) is a standard for the layout of the partition table on a physical storage device used in a desktop or server PC" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table If it's corrupt, your Mac has no idea of what to make of the disk.

Comment: The external hard drive was badly disconnected from a television. The disc has not been mounted since. There were only movies, but I think it's a mistake that should be able to fix and recover the disk as it was.

Comment: The disc had the format that usually brings WD, I think it was ex fat

Comment: But I'm afraid to touch something and spoil it at all, in case you have an easier arrangement to leave the disk as it was

Comment: This may help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206593/rebuild-partition-table-on-external-hdd-not-writable

Comment: From what I can understand in that article, the problem is in the map of the partition, which would have to be reconstructed. But in that case the disk is formatted for mac, and my disk was formatted in ex-fat I think. That would have to write exactly in the terminal of mac to be able to reconstruct the map of the partition and to recover the disk exactly as it was? (or similar)

Comment: What I need to know is, with the data I've put, what kind of format I had and what I'd have to put. And also in that part of the disk, since there are 3 options .. dev / disk3 .. dev / disk3s1 and dev / disk3s2, and I do not know where I would have to put the partition map ...