# Accidentally overwrote encrypted external drive (Mac OS)

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, recovery, core-storage

So I was rushed (and being careless) and accidentally copied about 80 MB of a Raspberry PI image (SD card formatted extfs) over my external USB drive (4TB) that was formatted and encrypted (using Disk Utility but not sure of the specifics).

I tried following [Recover deleted Encrypted OS X Extended volume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230379/recover-deleted-encrypted-os-x-extended-volume) and looked through [Rebuild partition table on external HDD - not writable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206593/rebuild-partition-table-on-external-hdd-not-writable) but still haven't managed to get the drive recognizable by my laptop (Mac OS 10.13.6 - where the drive had been mounted previously).

Running TestDisk did find these partitions (I assume from the backup GPT?) before I started making any changes:

```
#1557837238 Disk /dev/rdisk2 - 4000 GB / 3726 GiB - 7814037167 sectors
 1 : start=       40, size=   409600, Id=00, P
 2 : start=   409640, size=3518398048, Id=00, P
 3 : start=3518807688, size=   262144, Id=00, P
```

(Note that I think the sizes may be incorrectly reported as I didn't change the disk geometry before running the scan)

Following @klanomath's excellent instructions in the first answer above, I did recreate the partition table, so now `gpt -r show /dev/disk2` does give:

```
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  7813365343      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  7813774983      262144      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  7814037127           7         
  7814037134          32         Sec GPT table
  7814037166           1         Sec GPT header
```

However, `diskutil cs list` still reports `No CoreStorage logical volume groups found`.

I'm unfortunately out of my element here and not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @klanomath - you mentioned here (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206593/rebuild-partition-table-on-external-hdd-not-writable) to mention you in a comment but I can't add comments to that question any more, if you have anything else I might try?